# Is it possible to create Android statusbar notifications in HTML 5 Phonegap JavaScript application?

Tags: android, html, cordova

I want to add statusbar notifications to my HTML 5 Phonegap JavaScript application. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Our team](http://witcraft.ru) has released plugin for phonegap Android statusbar notifications. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/commits/master/Android/StatusBarNotification

Comment: Can I make it work with android 2.2 and 2.3.3? It's make error that my min api is 8 and it needs api 11, but with api 11 I can't run it on my android

Answer (score 1):

While PhoneGap has [a `Notification` API](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html), that seems to be for dialogs and beeps and such, not for Android `Notifications`. However, PhoneGap has a [plugin architecture](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins), so you (or somebody) could probably extend PhoneGap to support Android `Notifications`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Plugin to create status bar notifications

https://github.com/saileshmittal/phonegap-system-notification-plugin/blob/master/android-statusbar-notificaion/README